# Java socket program for client and server communication auto reconnect

Tags: java, sockets

I want to develop client and server communication and I have written some code for client and server but once the client and server connect, there's no need to reconnect again and again. However, in my current code they keep re-connecting again and again.

1. `InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();`
2. `Socket s = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 4321);`

The second line will create new connection each time and this is the problem I'm trying to solve (they only need to connect once).

**ClientClass.java**

```
public class CientClass {

public static void main(String[] args)  
  {
    System.out.println("CLIENT SITE");
    while (true) {
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            Socket s = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 4321);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Ener for server:");
            String data = sc.next();
            dout.writeUTF(data);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Serverclass.java**

```
public class Serverclass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("SERVER SITE");
    while (true) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4321);
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            String str = (String) din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("message:" + str);
            ss.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The clientClass reads commands from the console and sends to the server but it should not keep reconnecting after the initial connection.

And in a situation like restart the server and the client should connect automatically and and client should be able to send the commands to the server.

I think I don't need to change the serverclass code. Only need to change the clientClass code. How?

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question? It is quite unclear what you want to do. Also your code is a bit weird. Why is creating a client/server wrapped in a `while(true)` loop? That does not seem to make sense. Not to talk about the missing closing of your sockets...

Comment: yes please see again..

Comment: Have a look at the answer by L.Spillner which answers everything just fine and even explains it nicely?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so there are two main reasons why there will always be established a new connection.

First of all for every cycle of your `while(true)` loop in your ServerClass you're creatinga new server socket and await a new connection by calling  `ServerSocket.accept()` which is also a blocking operation, which means the server keeps blocking until a new connection arrives.

The second reason for this behaviour is, that you are always enforcing a new connection from your ClientClass by creating a new socket.
Sockets establish end-to-end-connections. Once created and conencted you don't have to make another one.

The most convientient fix for you would be to replace the `while(true)` loop so that it only covers the real send/receive logic in some way like this:

**ClientClass**

```
  try
  {
    InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    Socket s = new Socket( host.getHostName(), 4321 );
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream( s.getOutputStream() );
    while ( isAlive )
    {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
      System.out.println( "Ener for server:" );
      String data = sc.next();
      dout.writeUTF( data );
    }
  }
  catch ( Exception e )
  {
    System.out.println( e );
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

**ServerClass**

```
try
      {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket( 4321 );
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream( s.getInputStream() );
        while ( isAlive )
        {
          String str = (String) din.readUTF();
          System.out.println( "message:" + str );
        }
        ss.close();
      }
      catch ( Exception e )
      {
        System.out.println( e );
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: If i am writing 1) InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                       2) Socket s = new Socket( host.getHostName(), 4321);  
                         or(server side)     
                       3)ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket( 4321 );
                       4) Socket s = ss.accept();                                          outside the loop if i am restarting the server it can not reconnect again.

Comment: @BimalKumarDalei You are kind of right. Dealing with such an issue includes to check if the connection has dropped and only if it has the ServerSocket `ss` must issue a new `ss.accept()` call. In your implementation you are creating new ServerSockets constantly. If you really want a server service which can accept multiple connections and isa ble to let a device reconecct you should take a look at threading your application. The example for ExecutorService in the  [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) shows a nice example.

Comment: @BimalKumarDalei in addition to my above comment you yhould read this [blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) about "half-open" TCP connection. It is a detailed description of your issue and even offers a few examples of how to handle them. The concrete implementation is up to you. If you encounter some more issues while doing so, feel free to edit your post and leave a comment so i can take another look at it. Best regards.